# Displaying an remote image in Oracle Mobile Application Framework

Tags: oracle-maf

How do I display an image from a remote server using the Oracle mobile application framework (MAF)?

```
<amx:image id="i2" inlineStyle="width: 75%" source="http://www.somesite.com/path/to/image.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add (a part) of the external URL to your `whitelist`. That whitelist can be found in your

> maf-application.xml -> Security -> Remote URL Whitelist

More info and an example can be found on this blog: [MAF: UNABLE TO DISPLAY IMAGE / URL / …](http://adf4beginners.com/2015/05/maf-unable-to-display-image-url/)

Nice video about it whitelists in Oracle MAF: [Remote URLs and Whitelists in Oracle MAF](http://oraclesworld.com/oracle_remote/21__Core___Remote_URLs_and_Whitelists_in/147583/)